# How do I fix a crashing MySQL instance on macos?

Tags: mysql, macos, sockets

Had issues last night with MySQL. I uninstalled it and then reinstalled it and now I cannot get the server to connect after following some uninstall instructions here:

https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/uninstall-mysql-mac-os-x

^ I think this tutorial above may be the cause of many of my socket issues that are happening now

log file:

```
2019-05-13T17:35:42.702359Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.16)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2019-05-13T17:35:51.255099Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.16) starting as process 78228
2019-05-13T17:35:51.258608Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/mysql/data/ is case insensitive
2019-05-13T17:35:51.635376Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2019-05-13T17:35:51.641789Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010270] [Server] Can't start server : Bind on unix socket: Address already in use
2019-05-13T17:35:51.641800Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010258] [Server] Do you already have another mysqld server running on socket: /tmp/mysql.sock ?
```

netstat outlook:

```
➜  invisible-hand git:(2.1.0) ✗ netstat -na | grep LISTEN
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.53           *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp4       0      0  *.52772                *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp4       0      0  *.52607                *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.4244         *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp4       0      0  *.57621                *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.63777        *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.62722        *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0  *.61500                *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp4       0      0  *.61500                *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.1023         *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.29754        *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.29834        *.*                    LISTEN
```

After editing the `my.cnf` file to change the port in use it still has the output below:

```
$ mysql -uroot -p
Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (61)
```

```
$ mysql_secure_installation
Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (61)
```

```
/usr/local/etc/my.cnf
# Default Homebrew MySQL server config
[mysqld]
# Only allow connections from localhost
bind-address = 127.0.0.1

[client]
port = 3306
socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Inspecting the settings->MySQL the server turns on and off again.

MySQL settings/instance GUI:
MySQL instance shuts off after 2-4 seconds every time after `start` the instance, have tried uninstalling and reinstalling multiple times and the issue still persists.

I have tried installing through brew and still no luck.

Here is an output of my processes:

```
➜  invisible-hand git:(2.1.0) ✗ ps aux | grep mysql   
user         74665   0.0  0.0  4277256    808 s000  S+   10:13AM   0:00.00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn mysql

➜  invisible-hand git:(2.1.0) ✗ ps aux | grep mysqld
user         74676   0.0  0.0  4277256    808 s000  S+   10:13AM   0:00.00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn mysqld
```

How can I fix the socket issue and get the instance running reliably without constantly crashing? Thank you!

Comment: The first place to start looking for problems with a service, assuming they are not exposed by the startup mechanism, is in you log files.

Comment: @symcbean which log file would you look into though? that's not that obvious to me

Comment: The first hit in Google is: https://serverfault.com/questions/42531/where-is-my-mysql-log-on-os-x

Comment: @symcbean can you take a look at my updated post? I still have no luck even after going through the log file